# Two table merge in single table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have two tables in my database #1 is payment records and #2 is sales records of one customer now I want to show two tables' values in one single table that shows sales details and payment details at once like the 3rd image

So how should I write query that brings result set what I want.

I am creating this view in **php,** **mysql** and **html**

**#1 is payment records**

[image]

**#2 is sales records**

[image]

**desired output**

[image]

**sales table**

[image]

**Payments table**

[image]

Comment: Tried anything yet? Post sample data and expected output in the form of formatted text (**not images**) and post the query that you tried and what didnt work out?

Comment: I used inner join but it multiplying everything like cross join . JOIN ON customer id

Comment: How did you get the current images you have? Can add the database scheme for these 2 tables and/or your `join` attempt?

Comment: @chris85 - Looks like excel work.

Comment: @Sariful I think at least you have to provide the structure of your tables so we can know what we are dealing with. So please edit your question and add your tables structure.

Comment: So, the question here is: Do you have only one single record for each `customer_id` in these two tables? If yes, then the queries in the _Oleg's_ answer will do the job for you, if not, then how do you expect there will be only one row in the final query result for each `customer_id` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any of valid inner join form should work:

```
select *
from payment, sale
where payment.customer_id = sale.customer_id

select *
from payment inner join sale using (customer_id)

select *
from payment inner join sale on payment.customer_id = sale.customer_id
```

Comment: I used the 3rd one but multiplying everything thanks